# How do you detect Googlebot using reverse DNS lookup in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reverse-dns

I tried adding the following one-liner to output the reverse DNS lookup:

```
@System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress)
```

But it only returns the GetHostEntry function output.

I only need this oneliner to put in a if-clause which is the recommended method to detect a Googlebot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, I am not sure I completely understand. If you wanted to know if the `RemoteIpAddress` is coming from Google using a "one-liner" you are almost there. Something like this works for me

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("66.249.66.1")).HostName.Contains("googlebot.com");
```

That IP address is also the [known Google Bot IP address](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/verifying-googlebot). I hope that helped but again I was not sure the exact question you are asking.

One other thing to take note of is if you sit behind a proxy you will need to add something like the following to make sure the headers are correct.

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
    options.ForwardLimit = 2;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

Comment: I would rather use the remoteIP/client IP to verify, but other than that it's a brilliant answer.